# Add CompletableFuture values from IntStream to a final CompletableFuture variable

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to create a method which calculates in a CompletableFuture variable the sum of other CompletableFutures which are calculated in an IntStream. Unfortunately, my values do not add to the final variable that I need and it ends up as being 0. My code is below:

```
CompletableFuture<Long> finalAmount = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0L);

IntStream.range(rankUpEvent.getOldClubRank()+1, rankUpEvent.getNewClubRank()).forEach(
    rank -> {
        if (!clubs.containsKey(rank)) {
            finalAmount.thenCompose(startValue -> configService.getConfig(id, rank - 1).
                thenApply(config -> getAmount(config, "value")));
        }
    }
);
return finalAmount;
```

I need to have in my finalAmount variable the sum of each result computed in the IntStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum the results of a `Stream<CompletableFuture<Integer>>`:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> sum = stream.reduce(
  CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0),
  (f1, f2) -> f1.thenCombine(f2, Integer::sum));
```

The problem with your current approach is that `thenCompose` and `thenApply` return *new* futures, not updating the old one, and so you're creating futures and then discarding their results.

You need to get to a `Stream<CompletableFuture<Integer>>` and then apply that technique.

Comment: this is actually pretty neat :)

Comment: and how can I insert the value that I need to add to the sum without creating a new completableFuture to the syntax you offered? I am referring to this: finalAmount.thenCompose(startValue -> configService.getConfig(id, rank - 1).
                thenApply(config -> getAmount(config, "value"))); I am not sure how to combine them, I am not a pro in completable futures :(

Comment: It looks like you should just call `map(rank ->  configService.getConfig(id, rank - 1). thenApply(config -> getAmount(config, "value"))).reduce(...)` as above.